Override exclusive content for a repository defined in init.gradle script
There is an initialization script $GRADLE_USER_HOME/init.d/init.gradle which has an exclusiveContent defined for some repository and filtered by group:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
          forRepository {
               maven {
                  url 'https://the-first-nexus/nexus/content/repositories/deploy-it-all/'
               }
          }
          filter {
             includeGroup 'com.company.group'
          }
        }
}
         

This initial script is shared among the team and also it is applied for CI/CD jobs.
I need to define separate exclusive content for some specific artifacts from the same group 'com.company.group' in one of my projects to come from different repo.
I tried to achieve this by adding the following section with more narrow filter into the project build.gradle:
  repositories {
      exclusiveContent {
          forRepository {
               maven {
                  url 'https://the-second-nexus/nexus/content/repositories/public/'
               }
          }
          filter {
             includeVersion 'com.company.group', 'artifact-special', '1.0.0'
          }
       }
   }

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - the rule defined in the init script takes precedence over project settings. Changing the init script is not an option for me, I can change the project build.gradle only. Gradle version 7.4.2
Does anybody know if there is a solution to such sort of problems and if it is possible to override exclusive content for a repository configured in init.gradle ?

A Gradle dead end
Wow you've found a bit of a Gradle dead end there.
It looks like:

Gradle provides no interface for adjusting existing include rules for a repository
Any include rule that matches your target artifact will greedily hold onto it (as you observe)

I would suggest raising this issue with the Gradle team, but it would appear they have no plans to change the API for now.
Work-arounds
I see three possible solutions to get your configuration working correctly, none of which is wholly satisfactory:

Don't use your company init script and add the repo correctly first time
Delete the offending repository and re-add it with correct include rules
Adjust the settings of the existing repository by accessing a private field1 using Groovy magic

Adjust with Groovy magic
I'll illustrate this one as it's probably closest to what you'd hoped for.
repositories {
    named("maven") {
        content {
            /*
             * ***Unstable usage***
             * Accessing a private field of
             * org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultRepositoryContentDescriptor
             */
            includeSpecs.clear() 
            includeModuleByRegex(groupRegex, moduleRegex) // Come up with suitable regex
        }
    }
}

Here you access the repository by name. It looks like your init script didn't give the repository a name, but it the first unnamed Maven repo registered will be called maven, then maven2 etc.
You can then write the include rules how you want them: I suggest using a suitable regex for the module name so the include rule does not capture the wrong modules.

1 We want to alter includeSpecs in DefaultRepositoryContentDescriptor
